# How do I integrate the Box SDK into my android application for OAuth?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oauth, box

I've been trying to follow the directions posted on the [box-android-sdk](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk/tree/FixRefreshDuringLogout) github, however I have been highly unsuccessful. I've tried adding `compile 'com.box:box-java-sdk:1.1.0'` to my build.gradle file without any luck and have not been able to find a jar file to use.

I've also tried loading the box-content-sdk project into Android Studio but it comes back with an error stating the Gradle project sync failed and basic functionality will not work properly.

Has anybody been successful with creating a basic OAuth application for Box and if so can you please help me find the way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by putting `compile project (':box-content-sdk')` in my build.gradle file.